# Exclude characters using awk

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I am trying to find a way to exclude numbers on a file when I cat ti but I only want to exclude the numbers on print $1 and I want to keep the number that is in front of the word. I have something that I thought might might work but is not quite giving me what I want. I have also showed an example of what the file looks like.The file is separated by pipes.

```
cat files  | awk -F '|' ' {print $1 "\t" $2}' |sed 's/0123456789//g'
```

**input:**

```
b1ark45 | dog23 | brown
m2eow66| cat24 |yellow
h3iss67 | snake57 | green
```

**Output**

```
 b1ark dog23    
 m2eow cat24    
 h3iss nake57
```

Comment: Lose the cat (google UUOC). awk can open files just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$1)}7'  file
```

the output of your example would be:

```
bark | dog23 | brown    
meow| cat24 |yellow    
hiss | snake57 | green
```

**EDIT**

this outputs col1 (without ending numbers and spaces) and col2, separated by `<tab>`

```
kent$  echo "b1ark45 | dog23 | brown
m2eow66| cat24 |yellow
h3iss67 | snake57 | green"|awk -F'|' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/[0-9]*\s*$/,"",$1);print $1,$2}'
b1ark    dog23 
m2eow    cat24 
h3iss    snake57
```

Comment: That does work but I need to keep the the number that is in front of the word. 
I only want to exclude the numbers on print $1 and I want to keep the number that is in front of the word. 

Sorry should have stated that from the start

Comment: Try this `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/[0-9 ]+$/,"",$1)}1' file`

Comment: @user2607210 does jaypal's solution work for you? do you want to keep the ending space too? please add an output example for your input. so that we could see what do you really expect to have.

Comment: I have added an output for what I am looking for.

Comment: Jaypal's solution almost works but i do not need the the third field and iti s giving me the third field.

Comment: Ken that does not quite give me what I need and I am pulling from a file.

I get the following when I run your command.

b1ark45          dog23

m2eow    cat24

h3iss67          snake57

Comment: then you try jaypal's solution with small modification: `awk -F'|' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/[0-9 ]+$/,"",$1);print $1,$2}' file`

Comment: I got it thanks for the help everyone.


awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/[0-9 ]+$/,"",$1)}1 {print $1 "\t" $2} ' file

Comment: @user2607210 Click on the check mark next to the answer so that it is green. That's how you say thanks on StackOverflow. `:)`.

Comment: +1 but FWIW I'd use `awk -F' *\\| *' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/[0-9]*/,"",$1); print $1,$2}'` so it removes spaces both before AND after the `|`. The posted solution will leave spaces between the tab and the 2nd field and after the 2nd field which I THINK are probably undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]*\s*\|\s*(\S*).*/ \1/' file
```